# How to user fetch_array with prepared statements in Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Okay, I know there are a number of posts on this one, but I am still posting this questions because none of them are working yet.

I am trying to fetch result data with mysqli where the row count is fetching fine,but the row data is not.

Here is my code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from users where email = ?");
        $query->bind_param("s",$loginEmail);
        $query->execute();
        $query->store_result();
        $row_count = $query->num_rows;
        echo $row_count;
        if($row_count==1){              
            $row = $query->get_result;
            $email = $row['email'];
            echo $email;
        }
```

So echoing out **$rowcount** gives the correct result, but I am not able to fetch the subsequent data for this row using fetch_array(). It displays nothing. I know I am going wrong somewhere. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Where are you trying to use `fetch_array()`? It's nowhere in the code you posted. Also, `get_result` is a method, not a property, so `$query->get_result;` should be `$query->get_result();`.

Comment: my bad, but also get_result() is not working

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use get_result() and store_result() at the same time.Besides, it's just superfluous.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from users where email = ?");
$query->bind_param("s",$loginEmail);
$query->execute();
$res = $query->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
if ($row) {
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo $email;
}
```